# Rough Nose is Painful to wipe - what to do?

Tags: toddler, health, daycare

There is a horrible cold going around so I have a couple of rough noses that need blowing and wiping that are attached to children for whom this has been pure torture.  We have used moisturizers and jellies to soften little noses and I found some boogie wipes also, but even with the skin improving I now have kids that assume it will hurt and are screaming and fighting before blowing can even get started (three and five).

How can I talk to the kids about blowing their noses to make it less frightful?

Are there any nose blowing techniques that would also help in the future to avoide dry skin in the first place, and/or reduce the rubbing and friction within the process preventatively and now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In between colds, you might be able to use this method to teach your kids to blow effectively and reduce the amount of wiping & chafing overall.
http://melissawiley.com/blog/2007/06/05/how-to-teach-a-toddler-to-blow-her-nose/

Finally, a children's reference librarian can recommend more books like the one I linked below, to help kids learn about nose blowing in a fun way. 
[http://www.amazon.com/Am-Booger-Treat-With-Respect/dp/1931636583](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1931636583)

If your local library doesn't have a children's reference department or they have no recommendations for you, you can ask the same question of the reference folks at IPL dot org.

Lanolin works better than anything to heal up chafed skin (nose, bottom, whatever). Find it online or in the breastfeeding section of a pharmacy. Vaseline is a less effective alternative.

Little baby washcloths make great cheap hankies. Tuck one per kid in your pockets, purse or bra and they will be soft on noses to prevent chafing problems. Cloth is generally gentler than paper kleenex.

Comment: I was going to suggest lanolin as a barrier, the same stuff you use on your nipples if you breastfeed. A+D ointment might also work well. If it's really wide open, a hydrogel or hydrocolloid might make more sense. You could even try unflavored gelatin as a cooling coating that would help protect the skin.

Comment: Aquaphor also heals pretty well. I've used it and lanolin interchangeably for noses.

Answer (score 3):

Try the product [Boogie Wipes](http://www.boogiewipes.com/). These wipes have a saline solution so they break up snot and make it easier to wipe. They also have moisturizers to help prevent chaffing and chaping. Alternatively you could make your own using [this tutorial](http://alittlesomethinglovely.com/2012/11/14/homemade-boogie-wipes/). You can gently heat a wipe in the microwave so it is like a warm towel (make sure to test the temperature first). The novelty of it may make the kids interested in having their noses blown.

Comment: lol!  Then I guess I'm alredy doing everything.  I love that you can make your own Boogie Wipes though - that's cool.

Comment: These do help, but my 22-month-old still throws fits when his nose is wiped.

Answer (score -1):

If the nose is already chafed, a tiny dab of cortisone cream stings at first but takes care of it in a hurry.